# Simple PUT not modifying the model

Tags: endpoints-proto-datastore

The route is shown below and I can confirm the request is hitting the route, however, the model parameter is the currently saved model, when I'd expect it to be the model with updated properties.

```
@Page.method(request_fields=('id',),
             path='page/{id}', http_method='PUT', name='page.udpate')
def PageUpdate(self, model):
    if not model.from_datastore:
        raise endpoints.NotFoundException('MyModel not found.')
        model.put()
    return model
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `request_fields` field specifies what comes in the request, so you'll want to include a lot more. The `_message_fields_schema` property (discussed in [`simple_get`](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/simple_get.html) example) is best to use.

```
class Page(EndpointsModel):

  _message_fields_schema = ('id', ... other properties)
```

and then just let the default be used:

```
@Page.method(path='page/{id}', http_method='PUT', name='page.update')
def PageUpdate(self, page):
    if not page.from_datastore:
        raise endpoints.NotFoundException('Page not found.')
        page.put()
    return page
```

NOTE: I also changed the spelling of `'page.udpate'` and the text in the error message.